# Use custom color for component: ion-range

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to use a custom color for the component: `ion-range`.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/range/Range/

I tried setting the color `#ff0000` as below but didn't work.

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-range color="#ff0000" min="0" max="120" step="0.1" pin="true" [(ngModel)]="myValue">
            <ion-icon range-left small name="contrast"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon range-right name="contrast"></ion-icon>
        </ion-range>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to style it overriding SASS variables as described here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/. You can figure out variable you need using the link you provided. Just create variables.scss files and put the variable with the same name there. Make sure it goes after ionic style declarations.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom colors in src/theme/variables.scss

Example

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #488aff,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  custGreen :     #16e06d
);
```

and then you can use:
ion-range color="**custGreen**"